# Convert and store to S3 with REST API / InkFilepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

I have a Rails app on heroku. From the server side (using the REST API of InkFilepicker), I would like to convert a file, save it to my S3 bucket and store the S3 url to my model.

Concretely: Given an image (https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG) I want to convert it (https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/convert?w=200&h=150&fit=clip) and store the converted image to my S3 bucket.

**EDIT**

Here is what I did at the end:

```
after_save :save_thumbnail_url_to_s3

def save_thumbnail_url_to_s3
  convert_options = {
    fit: 'clip',
    h:500,
    w:500
  }
  file   = open("#{self.url}/convert?#{convert_options.to_query}")

  # Writing file into S3 bucket
  amazon = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
  bucket = amazon.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']]
  object = bucket.objects[s3_media_path]
  written_file = object.write(file, acl: :public_read) # :authenticated_read
  self.update_column :thumbnail_url, written_file.public_url.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the filepicker.io API you can convert your file with the API and then provide then use open-uri as below to create a file stream that can be sent to S3, `Tempfile` as below behaves like the `File` API in ruby

`[3] pry(main)> require 'open-uri'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> file = open("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/convert?...")
=> #
[5] pry(main)> file.class
=> Tempfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `aws-s3` gem : https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3

But be careful, Heroku is *read only* oriented, you will only be able to work on temp files.

Comment: But in the first place, how can I download the image from the url to the tmp directory?

Comment: Manipulate files on heroku server is not a good idea. I would look for an other solution. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Given an image (https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG) I want to convert it (https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/convert?...) and store the converted image to my S3 bucket.

Comment: But I should I've mentionned that I want to do that using the REST Api of InkFilepicker...

Comment: It looks like you don't need to convert the image on your server. InkFilepicker seems to be able to do it by itself (like accessing the specific url). Did you check this gem : https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails ?

Comment: Yes I checked it but the converted url is only cached for 24 hours, that's why I'd like to keep the converted image to S3. It's possible to do it in JavaScript but I prefer to do it in a collback of my model.

Comment: @NimaIzadi have a look at the answer supplied

Comment: Simply use `open()` : `S3Object.store("name", open("http://filepickerURL"), 'your_bucket')` (or something similar)